Michelson interferometer but with 1 arm (Part 2)
I designed a setup similar to Michelson Interferometer but with one mirror only. So, there is an angle between the 2 rays to the detector:

In order to understand the result on screen, I used (Zemax/OpticStudio) for simulation. The results are surprising. if there is no interference, the total power on screen is 0.96 W.

If there is interference, the total power is 0.49 W.

Note: I assumed the power from source is 1 W.
So, what is the reason behind these 2 different results?
